# JQuery onscroll length/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I have two textarea with approx. the same information how to make that if user scroll one than automatically another is scrolled. (textareas of same width)
I am thinking of onscroll event, but how to measure height?

P.S. I am using tinyMCE, if this info can help or change answer/approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start on how to do that, check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shahe_masoyan/2enVx/3/

```
$('#firstTextArea').on("scroll" , function (){
    var sctop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#secondTextArea').scrollTop(sctop);
});
```

Comment: This worked! If somebody in the future need how to make it with TinyMCE:
$(tinyMCE.get('text_editor_2').getWin()).scrollTop(sctop);

Answer (score 1):

you can do so using the scroll function

```
$(document.getElementById("txt1")).scroll(function(){
   $(document.getElementById("txt2")).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GXaGD/